# Date range partition table running out of time

Tags: mysql

A few years ago I created a MySQL table that stores traffic stats per day in a MySQL table (5 columns all INT apart from a date column). I setup this table as partition based on a date range with 1 month being in each partition.

This table is now at 175 million rows and will run out of partitions in December (I set up 50 partitions when I created it)

Question is: can I add more partitions to this table with as little downtime as possible? Or would I need to migrate all the data to another table definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repartition with an ALTER TABLE query. There's quite a bit to this so the best thing I can do to help is point you at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html).